# Prevent system freezes when opening certain files in VLC on linux system?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, freeze, vlc

I use Ubuntu 16.04 with the nvidia-384 drivers and watch movies in various formats  with VLC. Filetypes can be mp4, mkv, avi, wmv, etc. Occasionally a video will cause the entire system to freeze. Sometimes it comes back but usually it requires a restart. This is a known bug someplace in the video display system https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mesa/+bug/1574354

As mentioned in the bug report the bigger the files the more seeking occurs, the more likely it is freeze.

Is there any way to fix or catch this issue?

Comment: Can you please try using `X11 video output (XCB)`which you can find in the settings under video as output device and tell us if this still occurs.

Comment: @Videonauth I can't say it fixes it always but that did seem to fix it pretty well. What do you recokon is the cause? Thanks

Comment: I cant tell you the cause, but I have regular freezes of VLC with `.avi` and `.xvid` files and then I begun to play around with settings and this was what made it work for me. Seems that VLC on some files fails to set that setting which is by default automatic. Only difference between our cases is, i got no system freezes, only VLC freezes.

Comment: Thanks @Videonauth I can give you credit for your answer if you want.